# How to execute ln on find results

Tags: find, symlink, php

I want to make symlinks for image files in a directory in the server. Currently I'm doing it by executing this command using php function `exec()`:

```
ln -sf path/to/source path/to/symlink
```

Both file names are the same.

And it's working greatly. In the next step I want to make symlinks for other sizes of that particular image which are stored alongside the original image.
I searched and find this link: [Execute a command on find results](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25921/how-can-i-run-a-specific-command-for-each-find-result) which explains to use this format:

```
find ... -execdir rm {} \;
```

Now the furthest I got is to list files (full path) using find with the proper regex. But I have no idea how to use this output and link each file to the exact name in target directory.

P.S.: I only have access to the original image and its path.

**EDIT:**

As I mentioned I only have access to the image path and its filename. And I don't know how many sizes of the image is available. So I want to combine find and ln so that all image sizes of the original image file get linked to source files.
For example: I get the path to an original image like this:

```
path/to/file/microlancer.png
```

until now I was executing this command:

```
ln -sf path/to/file/microlancer.png path/to/symlink/microlancer.png
```

with an execution of a find I obtain these files:

```
path/to/file/microlancer-260x185.png
path/to/file/microlancer-120x120.png
path/to/file/microlancer-705x321.png
path/to/file/microlancer-450x223.png
path/to/file/microlancer-150x150.png
path/to/file/microlancer-495x350.png
path/to/file/microlancer-300x149.png
path/to/file/microlancer-705x350.png
path/to/file/microlancer-450x350.png
path/to/file/microlancer-180x180.png
path/to/file/microlancer-36x36.png
```

And I need a symlink in `path/to/symlink/` for each above file.

php is not a matter here. I just need the command in linux. I only mentioned php to clarify that I don't have access to all files.

Comment: It's a little unclear what you're wanting to achieve.  Would it be possible to post more detail, including, perhaps, the relevant part of your existing php exec() script ?

Comment: Also, what is the plan for the symlink path? For each found file, how would you determine what the associated symlink is? Please edit your question to include this information.

Comment: @steve There is a danger in it, his question may be closed as offtopic as a programming question :-(

Comment: Would you like to create symbolic link for all the lines in the list that you had provided, instead of applying your command `ln -sf path/to/file/microlancer.png path/to/symlink/microlancer.png` on the images one by one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find /path/to/file -name '*.png' -exec ln -s '{}' /path/to/symlink ';'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cd /path/to/file
find `pwd` -name "*.png" | xargs -I {} ln -s {} path/to/symlink/
```