# How to specify output file name using piping?

Tags: shell, pipe, calibre

I am using find to return the list of files from a directory and its subdirectories:

```
find $directory -type f -name "*.epub"
```

Then I want to use a command that requires the input and output filenames to be specified:

```
ebook-convert input.epub output.txt
```

I want to convert each `.epub` to `.txt` such that the output is stored in the same directory/subdirectory as the input. Simple piping does not work.

```
find $directory -type f -name "*.epub" | ebook-convert
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705/understanding-the-exec-option-of-find and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25921/how-can-i-run-a-specific-command-for-each-find-result/25938

Comment: surely that is the **input** file-name.

Comment: @pLumo Thanks! I was unaware of exec.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick is to *not* create a list of files that you then iterate over (see e.g. [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697)).

```
find "$directory" -type f -name '*.epub' -exec ebook-convert {} output.txt \;
```

This finds all regular files whose name matches `*.epub` in or below the `$directory` directory.  For each, the `ebook-convert` command is executed with the pathname of the found file as its first argument and `output.txt` as its second.

This would obviously overwrite `output.txt` for each found file, but the following would work around that by creating a file with the same name as the original file with `-converted.txt` added to the end of the name (in the same directory as the original file):

```
find "$directory" -type f -name '*.epub' -exec ebook-convert {} {}-converted.txt \;
```

This *may* not work with all implementations of `find` as it may not replace the second `{}` with the pathname of the found file (since it's concatenated with another string; but e.g. GNU `find` handles it).  To work around that:

```
find "$directory" -type f -name '*.epub' -exec sh -c '
    for pathname do
        ebook-convert "$pathname" "$pathname"-converted.txt
    done' sh {} +
```

With a shell, such as `bash` or `zsh`, that supports the `**` globbing pattern:

```bash
for pathname in "$directory"/**/*.epub; do
    ebook-convert "$pathname" "$pathname"-converted.txt
done
```

(this requires `shopt -s globstar` in `bash` and will process *any* matching name, not just regular files, unless you use `*.epub(.)` in `zsh` or an explicit `-f` test in `bash`)

Comment: In the last example, use `${pathname%.*}` to get rid of `.epub` extension.

Comment: This is such a well-explained answer. One query though: what do you mean by "regular files"?

Comment: @user110327 A "regular file" is a file that is not a directory, socket, named pipe etc. It's a file type in UNIX.

Comment: +1. also worth knowing about is `find`'s `-execdir` action, which works just like `-exec` but runs the command from the same dir as the matching file(s).